# Applying @PostFilter annotation to a generic Spring Data Jpa repository method

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop, aspectj, spring-data-jpa

I want to use the `@PostFilter` annotation on a Spring Data Jpa repository generic method (such as a `findAll`) as follows:

```
@PostFilter("filterObject.isActivated()==true")
public List<Advertisement> findAll();
```

How can I do that bearing in mind the those methods are provided "automagically" by Spring Data Jpa and are therefore not exposed in the application code?

Comment: can i do filter at fetching time [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048191/how-can-i-use-jpa-specification-with-spring-security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a `@PostFilter` to any method provided by a Spring Data Repository. Just override existing method findAll() and add your `@PostFilter` annotation as depicted in your example. Don't forget to add to your configuration where your repositories are defined

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

or in a java based configuration

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

respectively.
Keep in mind. This works just for collections and arrays. For every other return type like [Page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) you get an IllegalArgumentException. See [DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ummm. Do you mean to say the only way of applying @PostFilter is to override the findAll and other method provided by Spring Data Jpa? If so, it defeats the purpose of having them provided out of the box? Doesn't it?

Comment: It contradicts DRY principle in some way here. But it's just a "redeclare" of an interface method. You don't duplicate some existent code. So don't bother.
This overriding may be very helpful. Let say that your findAll() method generates a n+1 problem. Simplified solution here: All you have to do is override the findAll() method
and provide your own JQPL via @Query annotation. Spring Data will pick your query instead of the generated one.
Of course you can use AOP or a custom repository implementation, too. For a simple use case/application this is more than adequate and clean.